# Custom gdb output

Tags: debuggers, linux, gdb

Yesterday i noticed a nice output from dbg while going through a write up on the internet. As am new to dbg i googled a lot as i wanted to make dbg work similar for me. As seen below this customisation would help me a lot with my work with all the data displayed instantaneously. I tried voltron from the below link but was unable to get it working with many errors. https://github.com/snare/voltron

Is there any extension other than voltron so that i can get the output as shown in the link below? Would editing the .dbginit file help in any way?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg9JH.jpg

TIA

Regards

Comment: Are you writing `dbg` instead of `gdb` in your text on purpose, or is that a spelling checker wrecking havoc? You might want to check [gdb -tui](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI.html).

Comment: iirc you are looking at mammons gdbinit should be downloadable at woodmanns or at github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you show looks a lot like PEDA ([PEDA Github repo](https://github.com/longld/peda)) a Python extension to GDB. Although PEDA is very good, it looks like it is not being actively developed anymore.

A newer incarnation of this idea is GEF (GDB Enhanced Features) ([GEF Github repo](https://github.com/hugsy/gef)). It is written in Python as well and it has the advantage of bein *multi-architecture* (Intel, ARM, MIPS, etc.)

Both require a minimal change in your .gdbinit to work, no tedious installation, dependencies or anything like that.

Have fun debugging!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That  solved my problem.
It is time to have fun with PEDA and GEF than :)